# Updating Date Time Format specified in the regional settings of the system(Region and Language)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datetime-format, currentuiculture

When Application loads the date time format is displayed correctly according to regional setting in the grid cell, but when I refresh or reload the grid content after changing the regional setting. 
The changed format does not reflect in the cell.

So the format changes when I load the application first time.

Is there any way to change the format while the application is running.

Comment: How are you obtaining the formatted representation of the date/time? Can you show some code? Chances are, you will need to reformat the date/time using the new settings because what you have now is fixed as a string.

Comment: add some code to elaborate your problem.. did you check the `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CultureInfo data is cached first time it's requested, so it's required to call [CultureInfo.ClearCachedData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.clearcacheddata.aspx) method to get updated format values.

As a side note it's pretty strange that you assuming frequent settings changes during app runtime. If it's requred for app to have some sort of format changes it's better to make that an application option.

Comment: I agree it's strange to expect this to change so frequently, but I'm not sure I agree that duplicating the functionality in the app is the right choice.

Comment: thanks I just figured it out too.. Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ClearCachedData()

Comment: yeah I also thought the same but my client is specific about it. So was trying to grant his wish for something that should not be changed frequently